# Dynamic wchar_t array (C++ beginner)

Tags: c++, arrays, header, wchar-t

I am modifying some C++ code that has a `wchar_t myArray[MAX_PATH]` in the header file.

My modifications mean that I cannot know the length of this array until runtime. How can I store an array of dynamic length instead? Maybe I just keep a `wchar_t*` in the header file and another `int` to hold its length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::wstring` instead. It's a dynamic string containing `wchar_t`.